# Downloading a few thousand files - how?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, scripting, download

I want to download a few thousand files one by one. The average size of each one is 5-10Mb. Each has a name of "name_{i}", where "i" is a counter.  What's the easiest and best way to do that?

Note that the internet connection may be interrupted and I want to interrupt the process and continue it later. In those cases the next time I run the script or whatever it happens to be, it should take the last downloaded file and if needed re-download it.

Comment: @drewbenn, web page. no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can write a small shell script to do what you want.
Use a for loop to go through the files, wget or similar to download and write the current file to a file from which you can read where you have been after an interruption.

Example:

`if [ -f $FILE ]
   count=$(cat file)
   for i in {$COUNT ..5}
   do
     wget https://foo.bar/name_$i
     echo "$i" > $FILE
   done
else
   for i in {1..5}
   do
     wget https://foo.bar/name_$i
     echo "$i" > $FILE
   done
fi`

That's just the basic idea, there a probably some smaller errors, but you get my idea I assume.

Comment: Also, if you're going with `wget`, you might want to use the `-c` (aka `--continue`) option.

Answer (score 1):

```
BASE_URL='http://some.site.somewhere.com/some/path'
LASTFILE='./countfile'
last=1
[ -e "$LASTFILE" ] && last=$(cat "$LASTFILE")

for i in $(eval {$last..1000}) ; do
   echo "$i" > "$LASTFILE"
   wget -c "$BASE_URL/name_\{$i\}"
done
```

You said that `Each has a name of "name_{i}"` - I'm not sure if that means the filename has {} curly brackets in them or not.  If not, just remove the `\{` and `\}` from the `wget` line above.

If the filenames have zero-padded numbers (e.g. 0005 rather than just 5), you can use `seq` instead of `eval {$last..1000}` like this:

```
for i in $(seq -w $last 1000); do
...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `lftp`'s `mirror` option:

> mirror [OPTS] [source [target]]
>
> ```
>    Mirror specified source directory to local target directory. If  the  target  directory  ends
>    with  a  slash  (except the root), the source base name is appended to target directory name.
>    Source and/or target can be URLs pointing to directories.
> ```

See http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html for additional details.

**EDIT**

From the manual:

> lftp  is a file transfer program that allows sophisticated FTP, HTTP
>   and other connections to
>          other hosts. If site is specified then lftp will connect to that site otherwise a  connection
>          has to be established with the open command.
>
> ```
>    lftp  can  handle  several file access methods - FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, HFTP, FISH, SFTP and
>    file (HTTPS and FTPS are only available when  lftp  is  compiled  with  GNU  TLS  or  OpenSSL
>    library).
> ```

`lftp` can be used to get files over HTTP. Try:

```
lftp -e "mirror -c" http://url
```

Comment: I don't understand how it can help me, there's no directory on the server.